# Necesito ayuda para guardar imágenes en base de datos con java

Tags: java

Ayer tenía mi código en perfecto funcionamiento. Pero hoy que intenté retomarlo y guardar más registros no funciona. De hecho, no cambié nada en el código. Probé incluso con versiones anteriores del proyecto pero tampoco funcionan. El error es: GRIZZLY0155: Invalid chunk starting at byte [6] and ending at byte [6] with a value of [null] ignored

Analizando un poco el código, creo que el error está en que no lee correctamente la imágen, porque al comprobar si le llegan los parámetros, da error desde ahí.

Mi formulario:

```
<form action="SaveProduct" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="text" name="price">
      <select name="category">
             <option>Categoría</option>
             <%
                java.sql.Connection con1 = Connection.getConnection();
                java.sql.Statement set1 = con1.createStatement();
                java.sql.ResultSet rs1 = set1.executeQuery("select * from 
                producto");
                while(rs1.next()){
                %>
                <option>
                    <%= rs1.getString("cla_pro") %>
                </option>
                <%
                }
                con1.close();
                %>
     </select>
     <input type="file" name="photop">
     <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

Lo de java:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
float price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price"));
String category = request.getParameter("category");
int id_pro = 0;
Part filepart = request.getPart("photop");
InputStream is = filepart.getInputStream();
```

Antes de la clase tengo esto:

```
@MultipartConfig  
public class SaveProduct extends HttpServlet {
```

Ayuda por favor, estoy muy desesperado :c

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aveces es problema de netbeans al compilar me ha ocurrido que me lanza errores y el codigo esta bien, es aislado el caso pero ocurre, prueba cerrando el proyecto y cerrando el IDE vuelve a abrir tanto el IDE como el proyecto.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Creo que es más bien error de glassfish, así que lo voy a reinstalarlo a ver que pasa.

Comment: @WingsofRaven la respuesta aceptada es la que soluciona el problema. Esto soluciono el problema? o es solo un comentario?